# How do I get a equation to not break the margin?

Tags: equations, align

How do I get this equation to not break the margin? I have tried different things, do I need to used something else then align?

```
\begin{align*}
\int_{\R^2} \1_{[-1,1] \times [0,\pi)} (p, \alpha)  \Theta (\D(p, \alpha))
&= \int_{\R^2} \1_{[-1,1] \times [0,\pi)} (p, \alpha)  \Big( \frac{L_A}{\pi} \lambda \times \lambda \Big) (\D p,\D  \alpha) \\
% &= \frac{L_A}{\pi} \int_{\R^2} \1_{[-1,1]}(p) \1_{[0,\pi)}(\alpha) (\lambda \times \lambda (\D(p, \alpha)) \\
&= \frac{L_A}{\pi} \int_{\R} \1_{[-1,1]}(p) \lambda (\D p) \int_{\R} \1_{[0,\pi)}(\alpha) \lambda (\D \alpha) \\
&= \frac{L_A}{\pi} \lambda([-1,1])\lambda([0, \pi)) \\
&= \frac{L_A}{\pi} 2\pi \\
&= 2 L_A.
\end{align*}
```

[image]

I tried this, but then i get the same problem.

```
\begin{align*}
\int_{\R^2} 2\sqrt{r^2-p^2} \1_{[-r,r] \times [0,\pi)} (p, \alpha)  \Theta (\D p, \D \alpha)  
= \\
&  \int_{\R^2} 2\sqrt{r^2-p^2} \1_{[-r,r] \times [0,\pi)} (p, \alpha)  \frac{L_A}{\pi} \Big( \lambda \times \lambda \big( \cdot \cap [0,\pi) \big) \Big) (\D p,\D  \alpha) \\
\quad &= \frac{2L_A}{\pi} \int_{\R} \1_{[0,\pi)}(\alpha) \lambda (\D \alpha) \int_{\R} \sqrt{r^2-p^2} \1_{[-r,r]}(p) \lambda (\D p) \\
\quad &= \frac{2L_A}{\pi} \lambda([0,\pi)) \int_{\R} \sqrt{r^2-p^2} \1_{[-r,r]}(p) \lambda (\D p) \\
\quad &= 2L_A  \int_{-r}^r \sqrt{r^2-p^2} \lambda (\D p) \\
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Add a linebreak after the first `=` and move the corresponding `&` to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a slightly different method, using only `amsmath`.  the width of the displayed material will expand or contract to fit the available column width, but can be adjusted by adding (equal) blank space at the beginning of the first line and the end of the longest line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf{R}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbf{1}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathbf{D}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\int_{\R^2} \1_{[-1,1] \times [0,\pi)} (p, \alpha)  \Theta (\D(p, \alpha))\\
\begin{aligned}
&= \int_{\R^2} \1_{[-1,1] \times [0,\pi)} (p, \alpha)  \Big( \frac{L_A}{\pi} \lambda \times \lambda \Big) (\D p,\D  \alpha) \\
&= \frac{L_A}{\pi} \int_{\R} \1_{[-1,1]}(p) \lambda (\D p) \int_{\R} \1_{[0,\pi)}(\alpha) \lambda (\D \alpha) \\
&= \frac{L_A}{\pi} \lambda([-1,1])\lambda([0, \pi)) \\
&= \frac{L_A}{\pi} 2\pi \\
&= 2 L_A.
\end{aligned}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The `mathtools` package (which extends `amsmath`) provides a useful command `\MoveEqLeft` for this situation.  Put it in front of the material on the left of the equation and add `\\` before the equals:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf{R}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbf{1}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathbf{D}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft
\int_{\R^2} \1_{[-1,1] \times [0,\pi)} (p, \alpha)  \Theta (\D(p, \alpha))\\
&= \int_{\R^2} \1_{[-1,1] \times [0,\pi)} (p, \alpha)  \Big( \frac{L_A}{\pi} \lambda \times \lambda \Big) (\D p,\D  \alpha) \\
% &= \frac{L_A}{\pi} \int_{\R^2} \1_{[-1,1]}(p) \1_{[0,\pi)}(\alpha) (\lambda \times \lambda (\D(p, \alpha)) \\
&= \frac{L_A}{\pi} \int_{\R} \1_{[-1,1]}(p) \lambda (\D p) \int_{\R} \1_{[0,\pi)}(\alpha) \lambda (\D \alpha) \\
&= \frac{L_A}{\pi} \lambda([-1,1])\lambda([0, \pi)) \\
&= \frac{L_A}{\pi} 2\pi \\
&= 2 L_A.
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting! OT: I was unaware of the fact that one can define a macro called `\1`. I thought it was a to z in macro names....

Comment: @mickep -- OT: there are two kinds of macros -- "control words" and "control symbols".  control words consist of a backslash and a letter, usually a-z, but also any other character that has been assigned `\catcode` 11, as `@` is for "internal" commands.  a control symbol consists of a backslash and one non-letter.  (common ones are `\#`, `\%`, `\{`.) the digits 0-9 have not been assigned fixed equivalents, but are left for ad hoc use by the end user.